# Combine the SQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine two queries into one.

First query:

```
select SaleID 
from Sales 
where InvoiceStatusID = 'OR';
```

Second query:

```
select ItemSaleLines.Quantity, Items.CustomField2 
from ItemSaleLines 
inner join Items on ItemSaleLines.ItemID = Items.ItemID 
inner join Sales on ItemSaleLines.SaleID = Sales.SaleID 
where (ItemSaleLines.SaleID = {keyProductID} 
  and (ItemSaleLines.Quantity > 0) 
  and (Items.ItemNumber not like '%tnt%') 
  and (Items.ItemNumber not like '%contact%') 
  and (Items.ItemNumber <> '') 
  and (Items.ItemNumber <> '-' ) )
```

where `keyProductID` is the `SaleID` which I am getting from query 1.

I am doing this by storing `SaleID` first from query 1 and passing to the query 2, but it is not efficient and have too many calls.

Whats the better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
select ItemSaleLines.Quantity,Items.CustomField2 from ItemSaleLines 
inner join Items on ItemSaleLines.ItemID=Items.ItemID 
inner join Sales on ItemSaleLines.SaleID=Sales.SaleID 
where (ItemSaleLines.SaleID=(select SaleID from Sales where InvoiceStatusID='OR')
AND (ItemSaleLines.Quantity > 0) AND (Items.ItemNumber not 
like '%tnt%') AND (Items.ItemNumber not like '%contact%') AND (Items.ItemNumber <> '') AND (Items.ItemNumber <> '-' ) )
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh that worked just make little change on your post instead of = there should be "in" - ItemSaleLines.SaleID in (select SaleID from Sales where InvoiceStatusID='OR')